# pm2 does not apply changes to ecosystem.config.js on restart or reload

Tags: node.js, process, pm2

I have the following ecosystem.config.js file for my application:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'Worker A',
      script: 'scripts/workerA.js',
      instances: 4,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      instance_var: 'INSTANCE_ID',
      max_memory_restart: '1G'
    },
    {
      name: 'Worker B',
      script: 'scripts/workerB.js',
      instances: 4,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      instance_var: 'INSTANCE_ID',
      max_memory_restart: '1G'
    }
  ]
}
```

When the processes are started via `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` everything is working fine. However, if I now change the instances of the applications to a different number (i.e. 8) and try to restart the processes via `pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js`, the same number of instances will be started as before. `pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js` and `pm2 startOrReload ecosystem.config.js` show the same behaviour.

The only way I have solved the problem is to completely delete all the processes with `pm2 delete ecosystem.config.js` and then start them all again. While this works, it robs me of the possiblity to use the "0-second-downtime" restart that `pm2 reload ...` offers.

Is there any solution to this? Thanks!

```
$ pm2 -v
4.2.3
```

Answer (score -2):

scaling nodes only work in cluster mode in pm2 (https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/)

so add 
exec_mode : "cluster" to your configuration

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'Worker A',
      script: 'scripts/workerA.js',
      instances: 4,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      instance_var: 'INSTANCE_ID',
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
    exec_mode : "cluster"
    },
    {
      name: 'Worker B',
      script: 'scripts/workerB.js',
      instances: 4,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      instance_var: 'INSTANCE_ID',
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
    exec_mode : "cluster"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The processes are already running in cluster mode, I'm guessing that is automtatically set once you set the "instances" property to greater than 1. Unfortunately, adding `exec_mode : 'cluster'` does not solve the problem, if I increase the instances, the number of processes still remains the same after a restart of the ecosystem file.